# when setting border-radius on an input element in css the caret is gone

Tags: html, css

[border-radius set to 0.5rem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvDT1.png)
[border-radius set to 0.2rem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hElzO.png)

this is the whole css for this element:

```
.modal-input {
  background-color: #222831;
  border: 0.2rem solid silver;
  outline: none;
  height: 11%;
  color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  direction: rtl;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
```

edit: here is the html:

```
              <input
                type="text"
                class="modal-input modal-input-name"
                placeholder="folder name"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                class="modal-input modal-input-url"
                placeholder="url"
              />
```

I was expecting the caret to not be dependent on what border-radius is set to.

Comment: where you code html ?

Comment: @XMehdi01 added it

Comment: Please extract just enough code to show the problem and put it direct into your question as a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when you type inside anything there is this blinking line, its called a caret this caret for some odd reason disappears when the border radius of the input element is bigger then 0.2rem / 2px... @JamshaidTariq

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.modal-input {
  background-color: #222831;
  border: 0.2rem solid silver;
  outline: none;
  height: 11%;
  color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  direction: rtl;
  border-radius: 20px;  //  Just add in px
}
```

Comment: it did not help, the caret only come back when the border-radius is smaller then 0.3 rem now I did try to paste my code in codepen without anything else just the inputs and css for them and the caret was still there but when pasting my whole css and html it dissapears again

Comment: okay this is the code pen for my project (only css and html) currently working on the modal.

https://codepen.io/ReemX444/pen/BaveJLe

Comment: add in pixel and try

Comment: Still doesnt work in px